# Display data in a ArrayList in a Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have an ArrayList of objects and I want to display that information in a jtable. When new information are generated the table needs to be updated. How can I do this? at least some help.

Comment: Does the `ArrayList` represent multiple rows, or just one row?  A table is two dimensional, so if each element represents a row the class of object that it holds will need to be used to fill in the columns.

Comment: Here is a sample (read-only) table model based on a list (of Objects), which I've written some time ago:
http://puces-samples.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/puces-samples/tags/sessionstate-1.0/sessionstate-suite/sessionstate-sample/src/blogspot/puce/sessionstate/sample/ParticipantTableModel.java?revision=13&view=markup

Answer (score 5):

Extend `DefaultTableModel` or `AbstractTableModel` and build a custom model or just use the plain `DefaultTableModel`.  Have updates flow to this model and this will feed the `JTable`.

I would highly recommend reading over the tutorial as these are basic questions:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Answer (score 1):

> I have an ArrayList of objects

Sounds like the [Bean Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/) can help you out.

Or, if you mean you have an ArrayList of ArrayLists, then you use the [List Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/list-table-model/).